# Override docker entrypoint with spaces

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to override the docker entrypoint using **docker run**. This works in docker-compose:

```
  myapp:
    build: .
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    entrypoint: dlv debug local/myorg/myapp -l 0.0.0.0:2345 --headless=true --log=true --server
    volumes:
```

Using:

```
docker run --entrypoint "dlv debug local/myorg/myapp -l 0.0.0.0:2345 --headless=true --log=true --server"
```

Results in:

```
exec: \"dlv debug local/myorg/myapp -l 0.0.0.0:2345 --headless=true --log=true --se
rver\": stat dlv debug local/myorg/myapp -l 0.0.0.0:2345 --headless=true --log=true --server: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 10):

Check the article "[How to properly override the ENTRYPOINT using docker run](https://medium.com/@oprearocks/how-to-properly-override-the-entrypoint-using-docker-run-2e081e5feb9d)" by [Adrian Oprea](https://twitter.com/oprearocks).

> **[The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options)** clearly states that the ENTRYPOINT only specifies the executable to run, when the container starts.
>
> There is something a bit counter-intuitive here and if you take a good look at the example commands on the documentation page, you’ll see that the arguments are being passed after the image name.

In your case:

```
 docker run --entrypoint dlv YOUR_IMAGE_NAME debug local/myorg/myapp -l 0.0.0.0:2345 --headless=true --log=true --server
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending @VonC's answer in a bit simpler way, I had to override my `ENTRYPOINT` with `npm start` because I mistakenly wrote `ENTRYPOINT ["ng","serve"]` at the end and it was throwing error

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "ng": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

That clearly meant that `ng` was not added to `$PATH` environment variable.

So I had to override my `ENTRYPOINT` instruction to `ENTRYPOINT ["npm","start"]` and due to that space in between `npm` and `start` I wasn't able to run it easily

So as suggested by @VonC's answer, you can pass arguments after the image name like

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 --entrypoint npm ihamzakhanzada/angular-app:1.1 start
```

Where `ihamzakhanzada/angular-app:1.1` is the name of the image.